# error: multiply(long) is not public in BigInteger; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm trying to write a Java method that uses counts the number of ways to sequentially order n distinct objects - a permutation. Every time I try to complile my code, I get an error saying:

> multiply(long) is not public in BigInteger; cannot be accessed from outside package.

I tried replacing the line `fact = fact.multiply(i);` with `fact = fact.multiply((long) i);` which didn't work either. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Combinatorics  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 2.1
       System.out.println(CountPerm(9));

    }

    public static BigInteger CountPerm(int n) {
        BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf((long) 1);
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            fact = fact.multiply(i);
        }
        return fact;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To multiply `BigInteger`s, you need give a BigInteger parameter, not a long parameter. The method is [`BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply-java.math.BigInteger-).

Change your code to:

```
fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

As a side note:

- `BigInteger.valueOf((long) 1);` should be replaced by [`BigInteger.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE). There is already a predefined constant for one.
- Be sure to respect Java naming conventions: `CountPerm` method should be called `countPerm`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. The error is gone!